# Need a script/cursor that runs at server to look at temp on all the databases hosted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have configured CMS configured that list all my servers. I want to be able to run a script at the server to look at temp tables that exist on all the databases hosted on a server. I want to drop all the temp table that starts with 'temp_%'. Currently I have 14 databases on one server.

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
SET @sql = N'select name from [@DBName].sys.tables'

DECLARE @DBName4Loop sysname
declare @sql4Loop nvarchar(max)

DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases

OPEN dbcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBName4Loop

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    print @DBName4Loop
  SET @sql4Loop = REPLACE(@sql, '[@DBName]', '['+@DBName4Loop+']')
  EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @sql4Loop
  FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBName4Loop
END

CLOSE dbcursor
DEALLOCATE dbcursor
```

I want to be able to drop tables at once instead of running all at ones.

Comment: By "temp" you mean temporary tables (which names start with `#`) or actually physical tables which names happen to start with `temp`?

Comment: Physical tables that are starts with Temp_ only

Answer (score 0):

the following script will do the job:

```
DECLARE @DBName sysname
DECLARE dbcursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name NOT IN ('master','tempdb','msdb')

OPEN dbcursor

FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  EXEC('USE ' + @DBName)

  DECLARE @tmpTable sysname = (SELECT TOP 1 name FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE 'temp_%')

  WHILE @tmpTable IS NOT NULL
  BEGIN

    EXEC('DROP TABLE ' + @tmpTable)

    SELECT @tmpTable = name
    FROM sys.tables
    WHERE name LIKE 'temp_%'

  END

  FETCH NEXT FROM dbcursor INTO @DBName
END

CLOSE dbcursor
DEALLOCATE dbcursor
```

The cursor iterates the databases and a while loop drops the next table it finds, that prefixes with "temp_", as long as there are any.